# Constantly can't open youtube on Linux but being able to load it on Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows-8, firefox, youtube

My problem is that for some reason Youtube sometimes stops, I get "problem loading page" with Firefox and the same on Chormium, I'm using Backbox(based on Ubuntu). The problem is that I can open Youtube with Windows 8(from another laptop and from this PC(dual boot)). Also I can open Google the search engine. I want to note again that most of the time Youtube is working properly. I tried disabling UncomplicatedFirewall(ufw) and IP tables, actaully IP tables wasn't even active anyway, this didn't help.

Here's the traceroute output:

```
    traceroute to youtube.com (178.132.81.24), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  2529.611 ms  2529.900 ms  2530.549 ms
 2  ip-160-129.powernet.bg (91.148.160.129)  2534.699 ms  2534.667 ms  2534.624 ms
 3  178.132.84.97 (178.132.84.97)  2534.636 ms  2534.992 ms  2534.948 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

And here's ping output:

```
PING youtube.com (178.132.81.57) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=2.73 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=4.30 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=2.40 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=3.22 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=5 ttl=61 time=2.74 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=6 ttl=61 time=2.41 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.57: icmp_seq=7 ttl=61 time=2.92 ms
^C
--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.409/2.964/4.303/0.608 ms
```

Another thing I noticed is that on my Windows machine I can load microsoft virtaul academy(http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/), however on my Linux machine it loads only the HTML(no stylesheet). Any ideas why this's happening?

Comment: I saw something like this long ago, but it wasn't youtube related.  Adobe stopped Flashplayer support for Linux a while back, and as an alternative, Flashplayer is now sandboxed into Google's Chrome browser.

Note, flash is part of Chrome, not Chromium, nor Firefox as far as I can tell.  

So, if youtube is in any way relying on Adobe Flashplayer, you should be able to resolve the issue by downloading the latest stable Google Chrome .deb file from their site.

Not sure about your traceroute output, if your Linux and Windows are on the same network, it shouldn't be a network problem.

Comment: Only saw your MS Virtual Academy afterthought after writing my comment.  Sounds like you need flash.  Download the latest Chrome from google and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198: You don't need Flash to view videos on YouTube. HTML5 video works just fine.

Comment: @Karan I never said HTML5 doesn't work.  I said that if user445851 has a browser dependecy that would require flash, then he will have issues.  See : https://www.youtube.com/html5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159309/how-does-youtube-player-work for more information.  Bottom line is, he also reported a problem with MS Virtual Academy site, and this leads me to believe his youtube is trying to use flashplayer.  With answers like yours, people will never be able to eliminate intermediate possibilities as potential issues.  Very narrow-minded response indeed.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198: First of all, I didn't post an answer, just as you haven't either. Second, don't unnecessarily try and make a mountain out of a molehill. I was simply making an observation about YT not being dependent on Flash, but in no way suggesting that your Flash-related hypothesis is necessarily incorrect. Try not to be so narrow-minded yourself when it comes to interpreting others' motivations. I will say this though - stylesheets not loading on the MS VA site doesn't seem like it would be Flash-related in any way, so while lack of Flash may be a problem, it might not be the sole cause.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198: (contd.) Anyway, if you're sure about how to solve the OP's issue then by all means post an actual answer so it can be upvoted. However IMO any answer should deal with solving this issue on Firefox as well, since lots of Linux users view YT successfully on that browser without needing to switch to Chrome with Flash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23560/discussion-between-hitsugaya198-and-karan).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running browsers other than Google Chrome on Linux, an operating system that hasn't gotten a flash player update in 3 years, and you are trying to access two separate sites that both (can) make use of flash player elements, and it actully works on Windows (an OS that sitll enjoys Flash support), although no browser was named...

Since you are using an Ubuntu-based linux, I assume you would be able to install the latest stable google Chrome package by downloading it from google.

From command line run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/home/user/Downloads/package-name.deb
```

Replace *user* with your username, replace package-name.deb with the name of the file you downloaded.  Try accessing Youtube through Chrome, and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried updating Flash, Shockwave, JavaScript and clearing cache. I also change proxy setting to auto-detect. I have tried all of the methods listed in Google search results, but none of them helped.  After days of trying, I started to think of this may be due to my IP address being blocked by Youtube for too much usage.

Then I tried to use VPN to browse Youtube. Everything is solved. I think if you are a heavy Youtube user like me, VPN is your final solution.  Since many VPN are not free, have speed cap or virus and trojan to steal your bandwidth, I suggest you use Chrome as your browser and go to the Chrome online store to download "betternet" for VPN, which should be verified by Google and is totally free.